# Sort list of string based on length

Tags: string, scala, list, sorting

I have a list of strings

```
List("cbda","xyz","jlki","badce")
```

I want to sort the strings in such a way that the odd length strings are sorted in descending order and even length strings are sorted in ascending order

```
List("abcd","zyx","ijkl","edcba")
```

Now I have implemented this by iterating over each elements separately, then finding their length and sorting them accordingly. Finally I store them in separate list. I was hoping to know if there is any other efficient way to do this in Scala, or any shorter way to do this (like some sort of list comprehensions we have in Python) ?

Comment: Can you add your code for the sort here for reference?

Comment: @Shaido I found the solution after searching around `for(e<-lst) yield if (e.length%2==0) e.sortWith(_ < _) else e.sortWith(_ > _)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with sortWith and map:

```
list.map(s => {if(s.length % 2 == 0) s.sortWith(_ < _) else s.sortWith(_ > _)})
```

Comment: Thanks ! Although I did it using `for` like this : `for(e<-lst) yield if (e.length%2==0) e.sortWith(_ < _) else e.sortWith(_ > _)`.

Comment: you don't need to say `sortWith` twice: `e.sortWith(if (e.length % 2 == 0) (_ < _) else (_ > _)))`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you refer to in Python, so details could help if the examples below don't match your expectations

A first one, make you go through the list twice:

```
List("cbda","xyz","jlki","badce").map(_.sorted).map {
  case even if even.length % 2 == 0 => even
  case odd => odd.reverse
}
```

Or makes you go through elements with even length twice:

```
List("cbda","xyz","jlki","badce").map {
  case even if even.length % 2 == 0 => even.sorted
  case odd => odd.sorted.reverse
}
```